# VPN-ing to my LAN

Tags: networking, vpn

Everything is Win7.
I tried to setup a VPN to my LAN from outside(access to my drives, NAS, etc).

However I fail for some reason.
The error message is:
"The local device name is already in use."

Now the connection is supposedly set up properly. I have allowed access to my LAN from the VPN.
The VPN is set to Automatic and always connects using PPTP.

I set the IP manually on the client(and allow that option on the server). On the ipconfig of the VPN client it says some completely random IP, while the server reports the proper client IP.

The setup serverside is router -> cabled connection to desktop. IP is static, router DMZ to that machine.

The problem being that while it connects successfully, NOTHING works on the client(internet, ping, shares, anything).

**Edit:** Here's another piece of the puzzle: The HTTP server on the VPN server is accessible from the VPN client(by it's public IP alone). However nothing else is accessible(either by address or IP - i.e. google, etc.).

**Edit2:** VPN server is native Win7 one. Shares are accessed by IP.

Comment: what IP address does the router show and what does the ipconfig show on the client? What are you using as the VPN server?

Answer (score 0):

The internet not being accessible might be a problem with default gateway, you probably didn't allow for VPN users to go to internet over VPN but are using it as default gateway.

Go to properties of your VPN connection and on Networking tab select TCP/IPv4 properties, and then click Advanced button and remove use the default gateway on remote network option

[image]

Are you accessing the network shares by computer name or its IP address?

Try turning off your firewall on the computer with shares, to see if it's blocking the traffic.

Try remapping the drive/shares. (Your computer might be trying to access them with VPN credentials and that can give the error message you posted)

Also what network addresses are you using for the server, the VPN network and your local network from which you are initiating the VPN connection from.

If your local (where the VPN client is) and VPN network are the same this might create problems. And you might need to add static router if the IP address of the shares and VPN clients are in different subnets.

Comment: Hm, thanks. This solves the "no internet" problem.  However the **main** point of the VPN is access to my shares. This does not fix that problem.  **Shares are accessed by IP.**

Comment: are you accessing them by computer name or IP address, what IP do you get on VPN client and what is IP address of computer, you might need to add static route to access them if your VPN and LAN are different subnets, what are you using as VPN server?

Comment: Updated main question. For all other questions, also look there. It's not the firewall either.

Comment: In order asked: 1. Remapping does not help either. In any case, technically VPN and share credentials are also the same.  2. I don't understand that one... The network address of the server on the LAN is static, the network address of the router is static and real. The router DMZ is configured for the VPN server machine. The VPN server settings themselves have no ip configuration(besides the DHCP which is enabled, but allows clients to set their own IP).  3. I am initiating the connection from my mobile network(I tethered my phone to get outside the LAN).  4. The serv/client are 192.168.0.2/4.